# Simple Makefile with fortran files is resulting in Segmentation fault

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a very simple program with a Makefile.
The program `main.f90` just uses a module `cic.f90`.

These are the files:

**main.f90**

```
program main

use cic, only: pi, area
implicit none
real(kind=8) :: a

! print parameter pi defined in module:
print *, 'pi = ', pi

! test the area function from module:
a = area(2.d0)

print *, 'area for a circle of radius 2: ', a

end program main
```

the module file: **cic.f90**

```
module cic

implicit none
real(kind=8), parameter :: pi = 3.141592653589793d0

contains

real(kind=8) function area(r)
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: r
    area = pi * r**2
end function area

real(kind=8) function circumference(r)
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: r
    circumference = 2.d0 * pi * r
end function circumference

end module cic
```

Heres the simple Makefile I created:

```
#Makefile
main.so: main.f90 cic.o
     gfortran -o main.so main.f90 cic.o
cic.o: cic.f90
     gfortran-c cic.f90
```

this creates a `main.so` file but when I try and run it gives the following error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using a virtual machine running Ubuntu. 
Is it something to do with the targets or how I named the module file, should it be `cic.mod` instead of `.f90` or should the target for the module be `.mod` instead of `.o`?

Additionally, when I compile using the terminal writing the following:

```
gfortran main.f90 cic.f90 -o main.so
```

everything works

Comment: Please show the **exact** Makefile you have. You certainly don't have `gfortran-c` there... Also, why would you name the executable as `main.so`? The extension `.so` is for shared libraries, not programs. Also, which exact command causes the Segmantation fault. Even if it is just a simple `./main.so` please write the exact form you are using. (And BTW, `real=8` is ugly, not portable and evil and not the same as double precision, but I wrote it here too many times before.)

Comment: typo here ? `gfortran-c`

Comment: Sure, a typo, but it is an indication that we are not getting the real Makefile, but some simplification that might be useless.

Comment: That is the actual Makefile, I wanted to start simple so I didn't include any symbols
Also, I called ./main.so and that called an segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

```
#Makefile
main.exe: main.o cic.o
    gfortran -o $@ $^
%.o: %.f90
     gfortran -c $<
```

`$@` is the target (here, `main.exe` of `file.o`), `$^` is 'all prerequisites' (here, `main.o` and `cic.o`) and `$<` is 'the prerequisite' (here, either `cic.f90` or `main.f90`). See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

I second Vladimir F in *not* using `.so` as an extension for something else as a shared object.

If you keep having trouble with the code, show us the actual code, the actual makefile, etc.

EDIT: PS: if you copy paste the Makefile, make sure to replace the indentation with tabs.